# Getting null from JPA query in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have been getting null for my JPA queries in this Spring Boot Project. This is the project:

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Admin {
    
    @Id
    private String login;
    
    @Column
    private String Password;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AdminRepository extends JpaRepository<Admin, String> {
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT Password FROM Admin WHERE login = :login ", nativeQuery = true)
    String  getp(@Param("login") String login);
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {
    
    @Autowired
    AdminRepository adminRepo;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")                     
    public String home() {
        return "index";           
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/adminlogin")
    public String adminlogin(Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("command", new Admin());
        return "adminlogin";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/alogin")    
    public String login(@RequestParam String login,@RequestParam String password,Model m){    
        String p = adminRepo.getp(login);
        
        if(password.equals(p)) {
            return "admin";
        }
        else {
        return "afail";}
    }

}
```

I have used same structure and query in many projects before but this is happening for first time. All the queries both inbuilt queries and the native queries that I wrote are giving null but the same queries in the database shows that it is populated.

I have no idea why this is happening, If any one have any thought, please, feel free to share.

Comment: You are required to pass in a login string to the getp query - what are you passing in and how are you sure that it matches anything in the database? How are you sure that there is anything in the database this application is connecting to - ie  how have you populated the data in that database, and how are you verifying the same query works in there?

Comment: @Chris, what I do is to let the Spring Boot create the table for the entity in the database so that I am sure that they are connected. Then, I create a single login and password combination for admin directly in the database via insert command then use that to login in the web app UI. Its not the first time I am doing this and its not failed me yet. something clearly went wrong this time and I am not able to figure out what?

Comment: Why not try creating the admin login/password in the app and see if that is working too - you could have basic issues starting with basics like a typo in the login string value used to the transaction you are creating the row in not being committed/visible to the app. You haven't given enough for anyone to do more than guess at basic problems - show the SQL run by you and the SQL run by the application and maybe look at the value used in the parameter as a start. Or try a find all query without the parameter and verify you get any row back in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cracked the problem. As I mentioned before that I have used same method in many other projects and it always used to work, so, there wasn't a reason that it wouldn't work this time, that is, if I didn't do something wrong, something different this time.

My usual practice is to first create a entity then the repository then I run the application which creates the table in the database, only after which I create the controller and the user Interface.

What happened this time was that I accidentally ran the application right after       I created the entity, which resulted in the creation of the table in database. At the time I thought it was fine and didn't paid any attention to it, only now I realize the table and the repository were not connected. I then dropped the table and ran the app to create it again and it worked like charm.

So here is the conclusion:**If the repository is created after the table, the queries will not go through. Only after the repository is created, the table must be created.**